# fread EOF instead of separator

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I'm trying to read a huge file with fread, but i guess something is messed with the layout of the file.

If i try to read the file with

```
data = fread(input = "../data.txt", sep = "\t")
```

on this file (i just took the line with the error and few before and after):

```
ID  imdbID  Title   Year    Rating  Runtime Genre   Released    Director    Writer  Cast    Metacritic  imdbRating  imdbVotes   Poster  Plot    FullPlot    Language    Country Awards  lastUpdated Type
683 tt0000683   The Fatal Hour  1908        14 min  Short, Crime    1908-08-18  D.W. Griffith   D.W. Griffith   George Gebhardt, Harry Solter, Linda Arvidson, Florence Auer        5.9 26      Pong Lee, a Mephistophelian, saffron-skinned varlet, has for some time carried on this atrocious female white slave traffic, in which sinister business he was assisted by a stygian whelp, ... Pong Lee, a Mephistophelian, saffron-skinned varlet, has for some time carried on this atrocious female white slave traffic, in which sinister business he was assisted by a stygian whelp, by name Hendricks. Pong writes Hendricks that he has need for five young girls, and so Hendricks sets out to secure them. Visiting a rural district, he has no trouble, by his glib, affable manner, in gaining the confidence of several young and pretty girls. Pong is on hand with a closed carriage to bag the prey. One of the girls, as she is seized, emits a yell that alarms the neighborhood and brings to the scene several policemen and a couple of detectives, who have long been on the lookout for these caitiffs. The Chinese get away with the carriage, however, and Hendricks by subterfuge throws the police on the wrong scent. One of the detectives is a woman, and possessed of shrewd powers of deduction, hence does not swallow the bald story of the villain, and exercises her natural acumen with success. She shadows Hendricks, and by means of a flirtation inveigles him to a restaurant, where she succeeds in doping his drink. He falls asleep and she secures the letter written by Pong, which discloses the hiding place of the Chinaman. This she immediately telephones to the police, and while so doing Hendricks awakes and starts off to warn his friends. He arrives at the old deserted house ahead of the police, but escape is impossible, so the police rescue the girls, but fail to secure Pong and Hendricks, who afterwards seize the girl detective, and taking her to the house, tie her to a post and arrange a large pistol on the face of a clock in such a way that when the hands point to twelve the gun is fired and the girl will receive the charge. Twenty minutes are allowed for them to get away, for the hands are now indicating 11:40. Certain death seems to be her fate, and would have been had not an accident disclosed her plight. Hendricks after leaving the place is thrown by a street car, and this serves to discover his identity, so he is captured and a wild ride is made to the house in which the poor girl is incarcerated. This incident is shown in alternate scenes. There is the helpless girl, with the clock ticking its way towards her destruction, and out on the road is the carriage, tearing along at breakneck speed to the rescue, arriving just in time to get her safely out of range of the pistol as it goes off. In conclusion we can promise this to be an exceedingly thrilling film, of more than ordinary interest.    English USA     2015-10-24 01:44:09.623000000   movie
684 tt0000684   Father Gets in the Game 1908        10 min  Short, Comedy   1908-10-10  D.W. Griffith   D.W. Griffith   Mack Sennett, Harry Solter, George Gebhardt, Linda Arvidson     5.1 39      "You have got to keep up with the bandwagon or quit." This never impressed old Wilkins so forcibly as when his son and daughter give him the go-by, stamping him as a "has-been," and away ...  "You have got to keep up with the bandwagon or quit." This never impressed old Wilkins so forcibly as when his son and daughter give him the go-by, stamping him as a "has-been," and away out of the game. Even Mrs. Wilkins, who is as vivacious as a widow, snubs him. He keenly feels his condition and resolves to alter it. With this in view, he enlists the services of Professor Dyem, the celebrated Dermatologist and Tonsorial Artist. After a session with the Professor, beheld the transmogrified Wilkins. What a change! Shorn of his grizzly beard, his locks raven, complexion florid, eye clear and step elastic, he views himself in the mirror. He hardly recognizes himself. In fact, it requires his valet to convince him that he is he. "Am I in it? Well. I guess. If I don't keep up with and even beat that bandwagon by a city block, my name is not Pill Wilkins." He sallies forth and makes for the park. The first person he encounters is his wife. He approaches her in elation, but she mistakes him for an impudent masher and he receives the weight of her parasol over his head for his trouble. The next one he meets is his daughter. She is seated on a bench, waiting for Charley. He takes a seat beside her and when he tries to make himself known she draws herself up to full height and with a blow sends him backward over the bench onto the grass. Well, he changes his tactics, and gets reckless. Along comes his son with his best girl, so he decides to win her out for spite. Now this young lady has a sensitive pneumogastric nerve, and when he sits beside her on the bench and slyly suggests a cold bottle and a hot bird, she is "his'n." This is done so coolly and so quickly, that young Wilkins, who, of course, does not recognize his respected papa, is speechless with rage. He follows them, however, to the café, where his intrusion is resented and he is rudely thrown from the place. At the Wilkins' domicile there is an indignation meeting. Mother, daughter and son all rush in to relate their experiences to father. He is not to be found. Suddenly a hilarious individual enters. "'Tis he, the insulter: a drunk and disorderly." They are about to have him thrown out when the valet comes to his rescue and explains that the jubilant gentleman is no other than their dear papa, who has not only caught up with the bandwagon, but is sitting on the seat with the driver. They all gasp in surprise, and young Wilkins takes a wreath of laurel from a statue and places it on old Wilkins' brow, saying: "Pop, you are the candy."    English USA     2015-10-02 04:59:48.643000000   movie
685 tt0000685   The Feud and the Turkey 1908        15 min  Short, Drama, Romance   1908-12-08  D.W. Griffith   D.W. Griffith   Harry Solter, Linda Arvidson, Arthur V. Johnson, Robert Harron      5.8 13      The Wilkinsons and Caulfields, owing to a trivial dispute, had been at loggerheads for years and as time went on the feeling became more bitter, until they even forbade their children ... The Wilkinsons and Caulfields, owing to a trivial dispute, had been at loggerheads for years and as time went on the feeling became more bitter, until they even forbade their children playing together. The little ones, however, in their childish innocence, could not appreciate the odium of their elders, and Bobby Wilkinson and Nellie Caulfield became child lovers. This incensed Colonel Wilkinson, who tore the children apart, ordered Bobby never to be seen in her company again. The Colonel's action ignited the ire of the Caulfields and a furious conflict ensued, resulting in the shooting to death of George, the Colonel's youngest son, a boy of fourteen. From that time on the clans kept strictly to themselves. But love knows no clannishness, and, despite family hatred, Bob and Nellie remained lovers. After ten years, driven to desperation by this apparently insurmountable barrier, they elope and are married. Bob decides to brave the storm of his father's anger and present his wife, but the old Colonel drives him from the house, disowning him. Old Aunt Dinah and Uncle Daniel, the colored servants, were so attached to the young folks that they go with them. Two years later we find the little family, now increased by an infant son, having a hard of it. It is Christmas morning and no turkey for dinner. Old Aunt Dinah, believing in the efficacy of prayer, gets down on her knees in the kitchen to ask the good Lord to send them a bird. Uncle Daniel, touched by this demonstration of faith, takes a gun and determines to get a turkey at any hazard. Over the hills he goes, but his journey is hopelessly fruitless until he comes to the rear of the Colonel's house. Tillie, the cook, has just hung a fat turkey on a post outside the kitchen door. When Daniel sees it he can't resist the temptation. Back home he hustles and finds Dinah still at prayer, he lays the fowl on the floor beside her and sneaks out. When Dinah sees it she surely thinks it was due to her prayers. Well, the turkey is cooked and an old-fashioned Christmas anticipated. Meanwhile the Colonel has discovered his loss and tracks the thief to Bob's estate. Entering, a tragedy seems inevitable, but when the old Colonel sees the young one, his grandson, in the cradle, his heart goes out to it and the feud ends then and there. All hands sit down and enjoy a real Merry Christmas dinner. English USA     2015-08-29 00:33:15.610000000   movie
686 tt0000686   Fiestas del carnaval de 1908 en Barcelona   1908            Documentary, Short      Fructuós Gelabert   Fructuós Gelabert                                   Spain       2015-11-09 14:24:29.583000000   movie
```

I get this error:

```
>     Error in fread(input = "../data.txt", sep="\t"  :    Expected sep ('  ') but new line, EOF (or other
> non printing character) ends field 20 when detecting types (   first):
> 684   tt0000684   Father Gets in the Game 1908        10 min  Short,
> Comedy    1908-10-10  D.W. Griffith   D.W. Griffith   Mack Sennett, Harry
> Solter, George Gebhardt, Linda Arvidson       5.1 39      "You have got to keep
> up with the bandwagon or quit." This never impressed old Wilkins so
> forcibly as when his son and daughter give him the go-by, stamping him
> as a "has-been," and away ...     "You have got to keep up with the
> bandwagon or quit." This never impressed old Wilkins so forcibly as
> when his son and daughter give him the go-by, stamping him as a
> "has-been," and away out of the game. Even Mrs. Wilkins, who is as
> vivacious as a widow, snubs him. He keenly feels his condition and
> resolves to alter it. With this in view, he enlists the services of
> Professor Dyem, the celebrated Dermatologist and Tonsorial Artist.
> After a session with the Professor, beheld the transmogrified Wilkins.
> W
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what the error is in your data, here, but try running the code with

```
data = fread(input = "../data.txt", sep = "\t", fill = TRUE)
```

in the fread options. I had a similar error, and it seemed that fread was having trouble identifying my column separation. Setting fill to true allows fread to fill in any missing data- at least then you can check the resulting data frame and find out where the weirdness is.

Answer (score 0):

Add `fill = TRUE` in the syntax

What's happening: The rows in the data have unequal length. With this syntax, blank fields are implicitly filled.